# Why am i getting an error on return sharePreferenceUtils

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I cant figure out why it wont let me return sharePreferenceUtils. is there a better way to do this? I get the error "incompatible types"

```
    private static String Preference_NAME = "CodeLotto";
    private static SharePreferenceUtils sharePreferenceUtils;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    private SharePreferenceUtils(Context context){

        Preference_NAME = Preference_NAME + context.getPackageName();
        this.sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Preference_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    }

    public static SharedPreferences getInstance(){
        if (sharePreferenceUtils == null) {
            sharePreferenceUtils = new SharePreferenceUtils(MyApp.getContext());
        }
       return sharePreferenceUtils;
    }
    public void saveString(String key, String Val){

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, Val);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getString(String key, String defVal){
        return sharedPreferences.getString(key, defVal);
    }
    public String getString(String key){
        return sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: which line? please post the error stack trace

Comment: use     `public static SharePreferenceUtils getInstance()`

Comment: Yup that did the trick. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re using SharedPreferences as the return type of the getInstance method, and returning a SharePreferenceUtils instance. Unless they’re bound by some polymorphism, that’s what’s wrong.

Comment: Stupid mistake thank you very much

Comment: Happens to us all :-) Glad I could help. If you would be so kind to mark the answer as accepted, I’d thank you. Happy coding!

Comment: Absolutely thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Change your getInstance() method to below snippet of code you'll get return SharedPreferenceUtils.

```
public static SharePreferenceUtils getInstance(){
        if (sharePreferenceUtils == null) {
            sharePreferenceUtils = new SharePreferenceUtils(MyApp.getContext());
        }
       return sharePreferenceUtils;
    }
```

The return type of your method was **SharedPreferences** That's the problem.